# getting "NullPointer Exception" while creating objects in a loop

Tags: java, object

I am trying to creating objects in a loop.
while executing this i am getting **NullPointer Exception** like below::

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Test1.main(Test1.java:14)
```

**Test1.java**

```
public class Test1 {
public static void myMethod(int i)
{
    System.out.println("calling @"+ i+"time");
}
public static void main(String arg [])
{
for(int i = 0;i<=999;i++)
{
    Test1 obj[] = null;
    obj[i] = new Test1();
    obj[i].myMethod(i); 

}   
}
}
```

Is this the correct way of creating objects in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't created any array yet. Just initialize the array before the loop -

```
Test1 obj[] = new Test1[1000];

for(int i = 0;i<=999;i++)
{
    //Test1 obj[] = null; // <----------- don't want this here
```

Answer (score 1):

The array hasn't yet been created.

```
Test1 obj[] = new Test1[1000];
```

You're getting the error because the the array is pointing to `null`, and hasn't been initialized.

Comment: Note that this would causes Array out of bound exception too at the last count i = 999. You are creating 999 Test1 objects array, which index starts from 0 - 998.